# Difference between super(variableName) ; and super.variableName

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, constructor, superclass

[image] What is the Difference between `super(variable-name);` and `super.variableName = something;` in a constructor, when you want to initialize the parameters and you wanna assign one of them to a variable of a parent class?

for example i want to implement the constructor of the "Zahnradfraese" and it takes the parameter "int Kennung" and this parameter should be assigned to the attribute "kennung" of the parent class "Produktionmittel"

Should I always use super when I wanna call a variable from this parent class or I just use it if I have another variable with the same name in the child class?

Comment: as you cannot modify the kennung class, you can use `super.setKennung(kennung)` inside the constructor of `Zahnradfraese` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`super(variable_name)` represents a constructor call and should be first line in the constructor. Whereas `super.variableName = something;` means you are assigning a value to the instance variable of the parent class from the child class using `super` which is used to refer parent class objects.

Now in your case: as per given class-diagram
the class `Zahnradfraese` has a constructor which takes `int Kennung` argument. Also, `kennung` is the parent-class and has no constructor and instead it has method `setKennung()`. So you can do `super.setKennung(kennung)` from inside the constructor of `Zahnradfraese` class. You can also declare a constructor inside `kennung` but that would mean deviating from the class-diagram which has setter and getter methods and no constructor.

```
public class Zahnradfraese extends Kennung{
  public Zahnradfraese(int kennung){
    super.setKennung(kennung);
  }
}
```

Comment: Great! thanks, one more question please, in this case if i use setKennung, super will make no diffrence? i mean because Zahnradfraese is extending the Produktionmittel so it has access to its methods, right? and if i did like super.kennung = sth will do the same job?

Comment: @Sengo you are right. In your case the child class has access to parent class method so you can do that.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the difference between `super(variableName);` and `super.variableName = something;`?

`method()` (here, `super(variableName)`) is a method invocation (here, a parent's constructor invocation).

`super.variableName = something;` is an assignment to a parent's field.

> Should I always use `super` when I wanna call a variable from this parent class or I just use it if I have another variable with the same name in the child class?

`super(variableName)` can initialise the inner state of the parent, particularly `super.variableName`. It is reasonable to initialise a `super.variableName` before accessing it. Both ways you listed can be utilised for that. Just make sure there is no code duplication.

> I want to implement the constructor of the `Zahnradfraese` and it takes the parameter `int Kennung` and this parameter should be assigned to the attribute `kennung` of the parent class `Produktionmittel`.

Add a constructor to `Produktionmittel` which takes an `int`

```
public Produktionmittel(int i) {
    kennung = i;
}
```

and call it from the child:

```
public Zahnradfraese(int kennung) {
    super(kennung);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, i didn't understand what do you mean by 
super(variableName) can initialise the inner state of the parent. could you please explain it more?  and i dont have the option to add a constructor to the Produktionmittel

Comment: @Sengo the inner state of an object is the state of all the fields it possesses.

Comment: @Sengo a single constructor argument can affect more than 1 field (for example, it can set one field and participate in calculations for another one)

Comment: @Sengo, if you can't add a constructor to the parent, then `super.variable = value;` is the only option.

Answer (score 1):

So `super(variableName)` is invoking your parent class one arg constructor, and that logic gets executes

`super.variableName = something;` is assigning `something` value to parent class variable `variableName`

Answer (score 1):

`super()` is a keyword which is used to call the constructor in the parent class and it must be called from inside the constructor of the child class. Also it must be the first statement.

Where as `super.s` is used to set the variable `s` (which is declared in the parent class) from the child class and it doesn't have restrictions as above.

See below example:

```
class Test {
    int s;

    Test(int d) {
    }
}

class T extends Test {
    T() {
        super(8);
        int d = 99;
        super.s = 00;
    }

    void ss() {
        super.s = 99;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help, so super(8) will compile the constructor of Test class?

Comment: @Sengo, it will execute (not compile) the `Test` constructor

Answer (score 1):

super(arg) invokes the constructor of the super class, setting the variable just sets the variable. (The constructor might contain more logic than just assigning a variable, which you bypass with the second way)

Simple example:

```
public class P{
  protected String variable1;
  private boolean variableInitialized = false;

  public P (String s){
     this.variable1 = s;
     this.variableInitialized=true;
  }
}

public class C extends P{

}
```

calling `super("x")` within `C` will also set the boolean flag, as the parent class "might expect" it. Calling `super.variable1="x"` will not affect the boolean flag, and you can't change it, cause it's private.

As a rule of the thumb i'd say: If there is a dedicated constructor for a certain variable, it seems worth using it, unless you exactly want to override that implementation.